# How add multiple table id in single name column in MySql and join using type_id in CakePHP?

Tags: web-services, cakephp

My Issue is in my **REST API** in **CakePHP** for Favourite API. 
I have multiple tables, like `quotes`, `video` and `audio`, and one single table `favourite`. I want to use only a single field like `fav_id` in the `favourite` table and a `fav_type`, like 1 for `quote`, 2 for `video`, 3 for `audio`...

How do I join with the individual tables using `fav_type` in CakePHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the initialize function of your QuotesTable:

```
$this->hasMany('Favourites', [
    'foreignKey' => 'fav_id',
    'className' => 'Favourite',
    'dependent' => true,
    // Better to define a constant for this 1 somewhere
    'conditions' => ['fav_type' => 1],
]);
```

Now when you `get` a quote, you can `->contain(['Favourites'])`.